# How to output LaTeX code in line with PHP text statement

Tags: php, html, css, math, latex

Hope you're all doing well during such extraordinary times. I'm trying to display mathematical equations on my website but it keeps doing so centred and on a new line. I apologise in advance if the solution is simple, I haven't much experience in code and have been trying to find solutions by searching the web but have had little luck.
First I'm storing an array with my question and possible answers:

```
<?PHP $basic_question1 = array('Find the roots of the equation $${x^2} + 8x + 1 = 0$$','\[x =  \pm 4 + \sqrt {15} \]','No solutions','\[x =  \pm 4\sqrt {15} \]','\[x = 8,x = 1\]')?>
```

Then, in HTML, an input type radio

```
<form action="easyquestionsscore.php" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 form-div questions1">
                <p><?php echo $basic_question1[0]?></p>
                <!-- we can only choose one bullet point as all inputs have the same name -->
                <p><input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" > <?php echo $basic_question1[1]?> </p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="question1" value="2"> <?php echo $basic_question1[2]?> </p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="question1" value="3"> <?php echo $basic_question1[3]?> </p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="question1" value="4"> <?php echo $basic_question1[4]?> </p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

The CSS code is:

```
.form-div.questions1{
    margin: 50px auto 50px;
    padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #80ced7;
    border-radius: 250px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif
}
.col-md-4{-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}
.offset-md-4{margin-left:33.333333%}
.form-div.questions{
        margin: 50px auto 50px;
        padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
        border: 1px solid #80ced7;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Lora', serif
    }
```

However my result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9aCw.png
Has anyone advice please?  My aim is that the math equations won't start a new line and will follow the same format as 'No sultions' (being next to the clickable circle).  I have been using MathType to generate the LaTeX code.

 Cheers

Comment: You are using `P` tag which is a block. Override it's display to inline ;) 
`.form-div p { display: inline; }` or `.form-div p { display: inline-block; }` depends on your needs. You question should be tagged HTML , CSS btw

Comment: @Bobot Thank you so much for your response.  I have tried what you suggested in my style.css file and even done so within style tags in the HTML file however sadly it hasn't fixed the issue.  Do you know of any other possible corrections?

Comment: Good but even better it would be to change the `<p>` tags to `<span>` tags, being these latter inline by default.